# dynamic php to include file for different CSS pages

Tags: php, css, include

A few of my CSS pages will negatively interact with each other if they were all listed on every page of my site. The goal is to remove entire head section into a header include file to clean up the pages. I've tried to use a php script to look at SERVER's Request URI variable to detect current page and then use that in an if statement to pick the css link tags needed for that page. Here's what I tried:

```
<?
$currentLocation = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ($currentLocation == '/index.php' || $currentLocation == '/' || $currentLocation == '') 
{
echo '<link href="css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">';
} elseif ($currentLocation == '/signup.php') {
echo '<link href="css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">';
} elseif ($currentLocation == '/anotherPage.php') {
echo '<link href="css/anotherPageCSS.css" rel="stylesheet">';
}
?>
```

Is this a decent approach? Do you see any errors in it? Please advise.

I've also considered breaking the CSS pages down into one stylesheet, and use id attributes to target instead of having tag selectors. What do you guys recommend?

Comment: Thats one way to do it. But this can be a highly opinionated subject, as everyone has their preferred way to do things with dynamic CSS includes (and even building). However, a fully proper marked up html website can utilize just 1 CSS file. Just takes a lot of planning and discipline :)

Comment: What is your preferred means of accomplishing this? I'm open to suggestions as I have no experience. I'd love to get this working, but I'd also like to compare thought processes to develop my own opinion. ;) Thanks in advance to all who help.

Comment: I'll start by doing that in the meantime!

Comment: On a base setup I use page keys (a defined variable based on what kind of page will be built and returned, I never use the REQUEST_URI though), and then add 1 or 2 extra CSS files to include after a single global CSS file. That would go into a html header-builder method called at time of when the actual html would be built and output. Thats a basic gist of how I do smaller setups. Bigger setups are more involved with hundreds of smaller js/css files that get crammed together and cached and ... well crazy times.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for your input. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic example of a way to utilize page keying with a small class. Whenever you want to setup output for html, you choose which pagekey it should build from (that way, your urls and php filenames can change without worry):

```
<?php
// include_handler.php
class IncludeHandler {
    private $pagekey = 'basic';
    private $cssfiles = array();
    private $jsfiles = array();

    function __construct($key) {
        $this->pagekey = $key;
        $this->cssfiles = [ // define all css files to pagekeys
                            'home' => array('home.css'),
                            'basic' => array(),// if none needed
                            'accounts' => array('accounts.css'),
                            'checkout' => array('accounts.css','checkout.css'),
                        ];
        $this->jsfiles = [  // define all js files to pagekeys
                            'home' => array('home.js'),
                            'basic' => array(),
                            'accounts' => array('accounts.js'),
                            'checkout' => array('accounts.js','checkout.js'),
                        ];
    }
    public function headlinks() { // call this in your html output <head> area
        $html = '';
        foreach ($this->cssfiles[$this->pagekey] as $cssfile) {
           $html .= '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/'. $cssfile .'" />';
        }
        foreach ($this->jsfiles[$this->pagekey] as $jsfile) {
           $html .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/'. $jsfile .'"></script>';
        }
        return $html;
    }
}
?>
```

Example usage from like a checkout page:

```
<?php
// checkout.php
require_once(__DIR__.'/include_handler.php');
$htmlincludes = new IncludeHandler('checkout');

// processing code

// html output area
?><html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/global.css" />
    <?PHP echo $htmlincludes->headlinks();?>
</head>
<body></body>
</html><?PHP
?>
```

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks. I'm going to give this a shot.

Comment: I had added .js files too. If you dont need those, just remove the respective junk. But CSS and JS kind of go hand in hand ;) I also tend to have these sorts of things in 'another file', so that updating just the handler is a one file operation to expand on. Which incidentally you can combine this with a webpage header/footer wrapped system too.

Comment: I like it. I will use it for js and css. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

That is one way how to do it.
I would suggest using some kind of dictionaries for it (associative arrays in PHP)

Something like

```
<?php
$currentLocation = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$styles = [
  "/index.php"   => "first.css",
  "/"            => "first.css",
  "/another.php" => "second.css",
  //...
];

if (in_array($currentLocation, $styles))
{
    $link = "css/" . $styles[$currentLocation];
    echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"$link\"/>
}

?>
```

Just my opinion :)

Comment: I do like the increased readability of your suggestion over the if statements. Thanks for this.